# Create list property like 'description' field

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, csom

Is it possible to create a custom field/property like the 'description' field using CSOM. I can see how fields can be added and updated per list item but not for the list itself.

I was hoping to add a hidden property/field and be able to update this like the 'description' field

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set such a hidden property/field , you can use property bag. It can only be accessed via code and works like a key value pair.

To set property bag using CSOM, try below code:

```
List customList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");
PropertyValues listAllProperties = customList.RootFolder.Properties;
listAllProperties["SecretDescription"] = "Name of Dan Brown's upcoming novel is ...";
customList.RootFolder.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

To retrieve it, you can use below code:

```
List customList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");
context.Load(customList, l => l.RootFolder.Properties);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var keyValue = customList.RootFolder.Properties["SecretDescription"];
```

Reference - [Add meta properties to list](https://mohamedramadanahmed.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/add-meta-properties-to-sharepoint-list/)